# kubernetes multinode setup using kubeadm on different clouds/network

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, vpn

I am trying to create a multinode kubernetes setup on one AWS node and second server present in my lab using kubeadm.

AWS VM has private ip assigned on its interface(eth0) and an elastic ip attached to it.
Similarly my lab server has a private lab ip assigned(enp0) and a public ip assigned by IT team similar to elastic ip i.e. not on server interface

My single node kubernetes setup works well on either host but when i am creating a multinode setup, it is not working due to connectivity issue as kubernetes service is not reachable from worker node.

I added rule as mentioned in some blog as
`iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d <server private ip> -j DNAT --to-destination <server public ip>`

This rule is added on each node with ip of second node and after this i am able to reach private ip of other node directly. Checked via ping and ssh.

Then ran following commands for kubernetes setup on centos based systems

```
yum install -y kubelet-1.20.0-0 kubeadm-1.20.0-0 kubectl-1.20.0-0
kubeadm init
mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
kubeadm join xxxx
kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.20/manifests/calico.yaml
```

But my calico-node pods are giving error as follows

```
[root@controller ~]# kubectl logs -f calico-node-ws4g9 -n kube-system
2022-08-18 13:12:44.036 [INFO][9] startup/startup.go 396: Early log level set to info
2022-08-18 13:12:44.037 [INFO][9] startup/utils.go 126: Using NODENAME environment for node name node01
2022-08-18 13:12:44.037 [INFO][9] startup/utils.go 138: Determined node name: node01
2022-08-18 13:12:44.037 [INFO][9] startup/startup.go 98: Starting node node01 with version v3.20.6
2022-08-18 13:12:44.039 [INFO][9] startup/startup.go 401: Checking datastore connection
2022-08-18 13:13:14.040 [INFO][9] startup/startup.go 416: Hit error connecting to datastore - retry error=Get "https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/nodes/foo": dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
2022-08-18 13:13:45.042 [INFO][9] startup/startup.go 416: Hit error connecting to datastore - retry error=Get "https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/nodes/foo": dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
```

I am not able to resolve this connectivity issue between these 2 nodes.
I can change my lab server setting to put public ip on network interface but same can't be done on AWS EC2 instance

Can anyone please help on what can I do to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may check the routing table on the worker node. The issue I had was similar to yours:

- eth0 public IP on both the control plane and worker node
- eth1 private IP (e.g. 10.0.0.1 for control plane and 10.0.0.2 for worker).

Kubernetes is installed with `bind-address` and `advertise-address` on the private network. The cluster network is 10.96.0.0/12.

In the worker IPTables, k8s generated a rule that does DNAT from 10.96.0.1 to 10.0.0.1 (control plane private IP). This is all correct.

The issue was that 10.96.0.1:443 was not reachable by the worker node, using simple telnet. This is the kube-api address, and it makes the worker unusable if not reachable.
Contacting kube-api directly via 10.0.0.1:6443 was working (DNAT is converting 10.96.0.1:443 to 10.0.0.1:6443).

The issue was in the routing table, where network 10.96.0.0/12 does not exist. Because it is non-existent, packets for the 10.96.0.0/12 network are routed through the default gateway, which is public interface. Consequently, after DNAT, any request for 10.96.0.1 ended as a connection between  and , which is impossible.

The solution was to add routing for 10.96.0.0/12 network

```
ip route add 10.96.0.0/12 dev eth1
```

which changed routing table from

```
Destination       Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default           my.gateway.net  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
<public.ip.ip.ip> my.gateway.net  255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

to

```
Destination       Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default           my.gateway.net  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
10.96.0.0         0.0.0.0         255.240.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth1
<public.ip.ip.ip> my.gateway.net  255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

After this change, it was immediately possible to reach 10.96.0.1:443, and the worker node is running and joined the cluster. In my case, each worker node with private and public IPs should have this route added.